# ListBoxFor not unselecting between posts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have following code in View:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.GroupCriteria.Name, Translation.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.GroupCriteria.Name, Model.NameList, new { @class = "multi-select-custom" })
    </div>
</div>

...

<button type="submit" name="removeCriterion" value="Name">X</button>Name: @(string.Join(",", Model.GroupCriteria.Name))</button>

...

<button type="submit">@Translation.Update</button>
```

And in controller:

```
public ActionResult GetUsers(GroupCriteriaModel groupCriteria, string removeCriterion)
{
    if("Name".Equals(removeCriterion)) groupCriteria.Name.Clear();
    ...
    return View(modelWithCriterias);
}
```

Now what is happening:

When I select/unselect some values by clicking in select then click "Update", everything works fine: selection in returned page is same as what was posted.

Now i click "X" to clear "Name". "removeCriterion" is equal to "Name", so Name list is cleared (in debugger I see it is empty). Debugger in View: "Model.GroupCriteria.Name" is still empty, none of "Model.NameList" is "Selected" (set true). But returned HTML contains same selection as before (same items have attribute 'selected="selected"').

Is this some kind of caching done by MVC? How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is being binded from `ModelState`, so you should clear it:

```
if("Name".Equals(removeCriterion))
{
    groupCriteria.Name.Clear();
    ModelState.Clear();
}
```

If you want to perform the operation in more specific way, you can use `ModelState.Remove()` in order to remove only the state related to your ListBox.